# Deleting row from Data Table bound to a DataGridView -C#

Tags: .net, datagridview

I've bound a DataGridView to a MySql table, although I'm having trouble simultaneously deleting a row from the DataGridView control and the MySql table.

Here was my attempt:

```
    //* I used a class called "mySqlInterface to bind my DataGridView control.
    //* "dataTable" is a DataTable that gets filled by the database table
     private void deleteButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string accountNum =    clientDGV.SelectedRows[0].Cells[clientDGV.SelectedRows[0].Cells.Count - 1].Value.ToString();
        string selectStr = "account_number = " + accountNum;
        DataRow rowToDelete = mySqlInterface.dataTable.Select(selectStr)[0];
        mySqlInterface.dataTable.Rows.Remove(rowToDelete);
        mySqlInterface.Save(); 
       //Save() executes mySqlDataAdapter.Update(dataTable);
    }
```

This removed the selected row from the DGV, but not from the DB.

Any tips? Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1):

Why do you comment the last line?

Try this code:

```
mySqlDataAdapter.Update(mySqlInterface.dataTable);
```

Comment: The last comment just explains that the Save() function essentially just executes the Update() function within the mySqlInterface class.     -Ok, it seems I figured it out. All I had to do was this:      DataRow rowToDelete = mySqlInterface.dataTable.Select(selectStr)[0];
            rowToDelete.Delete(); If you have a cleaner way doing this, I'm all ears. Thanks!

Comment: You can add an extension method called "Delete" to the type "
System.Data.DataRow", in this method, you just write code to delete this row from both DataGridView and DB.

Comment: The code may like this: 
public static void Delete(this DataRow dr)
{
    // Delete from DataGridView
    ...
    // Delete from DB
    ...
}

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured it out a few weeks ago:

```
    string accountNum = clientDGV.SelectedRows[0].Cells[clientDGV.SelectedRows[0].Cells.Count - 1].Value.ToString();
        string selectStr = "account_number = " + accountNum;
        DataRow rowToDelete = mySqlInterface.dataTable.Select(selectStr)[0];
        rowToDelete.Delete();
        mySqlInterface.Save();
```

The only difference between the code I have in my question and the code above is the replacement of the line
        mySqlInterface.dataTable.Rows.Remove(rowToDelete);
with the line
        rowToDelete.Delete();

Right when I selected what row to delete I used the Delete() function. I'm kind of an idiot for not trying this earlier.

If anyone has a cleaner way to do this, I'm all ears! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Since the datagridview is already bounded to your datatable, the only thing you need to do is to delete the row from it and VB will take care of your datatable.

```
 For i As Integer = 0 To [datagridview].Rows.Count - 2 
   Me.dgDetalleNota.Rows.RemoveAt(0)    
Next i
```